# OKD Production Cluster Architecture

Tags: architecture, openshift, cluster-computing, redhat, okd

I would like to create a production cluster with 6 nodes:
3 master-etcd nodes and 3 computing nodes. I'm using external balancing machine for masters. 
My questions are:

1. Is it possible to install infra nodes on computing nodes?
2. I know that EFK is installed by default in OKD cluster, so is it possible to disable the installation of EFK component?

Thank you for your answers in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to install infra nodes on computing nodes?

Infra nodes are nothing but worker nodes that you designate to run certain workloads (using some combination of labels, taints, tolerances, affinity, and anti-affinity rules), so you can not deploy special nodes at all and by default everything will run across the worker nodes.

The smallest recommended HA configuration for OpenShift / OKD is 3 Control Plane hosts and 2 Worker hosts, so your architecture is sufficient for an HA setup.

> I know that EFK is installed by default in OKD cluster, so is it possible to disable the installation of EFK component?

The [cluster-logging operator](https://github.com/openshift/cluster-logging-operator) (what provides EFK) is not installed by default, though there are other cluster operators are installed by default that you can't disable (the [cluster-monitoring operator](https://github.com/openshift/cluster-monitoring-operator) for example).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!
So you're saying that, for example, situation where we have 2 master-etcd-infra nodes and 2+ worker nodes will not word, right?

Comment: As of OpenShift / OKD 4.4 you have to have 3 master nodes and 1+ Worker nodes. There are plans to make OpenShift more friendly to edge scenarios and in 4.5+ it may be possible to deploy a 3 Master 0 Worker cluster and in 4.6+ it may be possible to deploy a single node cluster.